# How to redirect the user to the detailview page after form submission in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('url',)
```

I have a detail page for model. The url is the following: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sites/10/`
Now I need to make a form. Where the user will add new site. And after adding the new site, I want to redirect him to this detail page url with his site id.

Here is the urls.py path:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .views import RobotView, SiteView, add_site

app_name = 'checks'

urlpatterns = [
    path('robots/<int:pk>/', RobotView.as_view(), name='robots'),
    path('sites/<int:pk>/', SiteView.as_view(), name='sites'),
    path('add/', add_site, name='add_site'),
]
```

and here is the view:

```
def add_site(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddSiteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('checks:sites', url.pk)
    else:
        form = AddSiteForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', { 'form': form })
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: instance = form.save()  return redirect('checks:sites', instance.pk)

Answer (score 0):

```
path('robots/<int:pk>/', RobotView.as_view(), name='robots')
```

By the name you can return redirect()

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
 //pk must be the same variable as define in path(/<int:**pk**>)
 def anyFunction_in_Views.py(request,pk):
    AnyModel.objects.filter(primarykey==pk)
    return render()
```

Comment: yes, I know. But I need to redirect to sites. And sites need pk. the questioin is how to pass the pk

Comment: please rewrite your question in a reasonable way then.